# need help to write sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add prefix in my result.

I tried below SQL code to get my result.

```
Select * 
FROM human_resources hr
      left JOIN account_group ac
    ON ac.NAME = hr.user_name 
   AND ac.adgroup = hr.name
left join controll_aduser qa 
    on right(hr.user_name, length(hr.user_name) - 7) = UPPER(qa.user_name)
left join employee e
    on qa.employee_code = e.employee_code
```

I am not getting any error related to above SQL query but the problem is in table human_resources user_name is mention for eg: `DI-SHA\QALAM` and I want to add  `DI-SHA\` in Table control_aduser field because in that table user_name is mentioned as 'qalam' in small letters.

Answer (score 1):

In postgresql you can concatenate strings with the `||` operator:

```
SELECT 'DI-SHA\' || UPPER(hr.user_name) 
FROM human_resources hr 
  left JOIN account_group ac 
         ON ac.NAME = hr.user_name 
        AND ac.adgroup = hr.name 
  left join controll_aduser qa 
        on right(hr.user_name, length(hr.user_name) - 7) = UPPER(qa.user_name) 
  left join employee e 
         on qa.employee_code = e.employee_code
```

Comment: what if 'DI-SHA\' is there and one more is used in user_name i.e. 'RAWAT\' then it will take only 'DI-SHA\' only and user_name with 'RAWAT\AALAM' would not be retrieved.

Comment: I'm not sure of what are you asking now. Maybe if you have an example. Anyway, I'm pretty sure it can be done with conditional expressions and pattern matching

Comment: for eg: table 1                            table 2
           DI-SHA\AALAM            aalam                                                                                                         or table1 can contain RAWAT\ prefix also so how pattern matching will be done in sql or I have to use CASE logic statement.

Comment: I still don't understand the conditon when 'DI-SHA\' has to be concatenated and when 'RAWAT\' and when 'AD-ONE\'. You could edit the question to be more specific with this examples so we can try to help

Answer (score 0):

You just CONCAT() the USERNAME and wrap it with an UPPER()

```
concat('DI-SHA\',UPPER(USER_NAME))
```